# Visibility of imported constants in angular templates

Tags: angular

Currently I have multiple modules with duplicated options as class field:

```js
...
    options = ['opt1','opt1']
...
```

I wanted to extract duplicated options to constants module and import them in each component that requires it.

```js
//some.component.ts
import {OPTIONS} from "../constants";
...
```

```html
<!--  some.component.html -->
          <select class="form-control" id="myOptions"
                required>
          <option *ngFor="let opt of OPTIONS" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
          </select>
```

```js
//constants.ts
export const OPTIONS = ['opt1', 'opt2'];
```

I get `Unresolved variable of type OPTIONS` error.
It works fine when i just declare field in each component.

How to avoid this duplication in different components?

Comment: I would say you can't avoid this field duplication => **public options = OPTIONS;** This would go opposite direction of the encapsulation needed in component oriented programmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to avoid declare the options in each of your components

```js
// real.component.ts
import {OPTIONS} from "../constants";

export class RealComponent {
    options = OPTIONS;
}
```

You can create some kind of Abstract Component, declare the field options = OPTIONS;

```js
// abstract-options.component.ts
import {OPTIONS} from "../constants";

export class AbstractOptionsComponent {

  options = OPTIONS;
}
```

Then you can extend your abstract component to get the only once declared options

```js
// real.component.ts

export class RealComponent extends AbstractOptionsComponent {

  // this.options would be available here
}
```

And use it simply in your real.component.html

```html
<!--  real.component.html -->
<select class="form-control" id="myOptions" required>
   <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an enum, as for example:

```
export enum Operation {
  opt1 = 1,
  opt2 = 2,
  opt3 = 3
}

...

import { Options } from 'options.enum';
public option = Options;
...
this.option.opt1
...
```

Or also use an array:

```
export const Options = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'opt1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'opt2'
  },
{
    id: 2,
    label: 'opt2'
  }
];

...
options = Options;
let selected = options.find(option => option.id === n).label;
...
```

As you prefer. There are a lot of ways to achieve this.

Comment: I'm trying different ways, so it has to be a component class member? Otherwise template won't see it?

Comment: It has  to be a component class membe ! Yes !

Answer (score 1):

The variables in the template could only resolve it's specific component member variables. Only importing the variables doesn't initialize a member variable. You would still need to do it manually for each component.

```js
// some.component.ts
import {OPTIONS} from "../constants";

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  // the variables used in the template would try 
  // to resolve ONLY within this class' scope

  options = OPTIONS;
}
```

```html
<!--  some.component.html -->
<select class="form-control" id="myOptions" required>
  <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
</select>
```